# How to enable suspend-then-hibernate when hibernate works in 23.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate, 23.10

In 23.10 `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` results in

```
Call to SuspendThenHibernate failed: Sleep verb "suspend-then-hibernate" not supported
```

but `systemctl hibernate` works just fine and as expected.
I have a `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/sleep_overrides.conf` file with the below continence. Is there something else I need to add or update?

```
   1   │ [Sleep]
   2   │ AllowSuspend=
   3   │ AllowSuspend=yes
   4   │ AllowHibernation=
   5   │ AllowHibernation=yes
   6   │ AllowSuspendThenHibernate=
   7   │ AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
   8   │ AllowHybridSleep=
   9   │ AllowHybridSleep=yes
  10   │ SuspendMode=
  11   │ #SuspendMode=hybrid-sleep
  12   │ SuspendMode=suspend-then-hibernate
  13   │ HibernateDelaySec=
  14   │ HibernateDelaySec=25min
  15   │ SuspendEstimationSec=
  16   │ SuspendEstimationSec=30min
───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

`/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` is unmodified with the contents below

```
   1   │ #  This file is part of systemd.
   2   │ #
   3   │ #  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
   4   │ #  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
   5   │ #  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
   6   │ #  any later version.
   7   │ #
   8   │ # Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
   9   │ # should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
  10   │ # the sleep.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
  11   │ # Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
  12   │ #
  13   │ # See systemd-sleep.conf(5) for details.
  14   │ 
  15   │ [Sleep]
  16   │ #AllowSuspend=yes
  17   │ #AllowHibernation=yes
  18   │ #AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
  19   │ #AllowHybridSleep=yes
  20   │ #SuspendMode=
  21   │ #SuspendState=mem standby freeze
  22   │ #HibernateMode=platform shutdown
  23   │ #HibernateState=disk
  24   │ #HybridSleepMode=suspend platform shutdown
  25   │ #HybridSleepState=disk
  26   │ #HibernateDelaySec=
  27   │ #SuspendEstimationSec=60min
───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've tried that already to no avail.

Comment: Let's start with a clean state. Rename the `sleep_overrides.conf` to `sleep_overrides.backup.conf`. Restart and see if that helps.

Comment: Also add the contents of `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` in your question.

Comment: Renaming `sleep_overrides.conf` to `sleep_overrides.backup.conf` unfortunately has the same results.

Comment: Added `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` to the description

Comment: I am out of ideas.